# SQL add "non-existing" rows to results based for all variants and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I’m trying to add virtual (non-existing) rows to get a list of all available translations in the system

What I want to get is like below:
(example 1)

```
id     title     source_langcode    target_langcode |    (type)
----------------------------------------------------|
...                                                 |
205   Iriure EN         en               en         | ⟵ original
205   Iriure EN         en               de         | ⟵ non translated (virtual)
205   IriUKure          en               uk         | ⟵ translation
...                                                 |
```

What I'm having now:
(example 2)

```
id     title     source_langcode    target_langcode |  
----------------------------------------------------|
...                                                 |
205   Iriure EN         en               en         | ⟵ original                
205   IriUKure          uk          DYMMY_LANGCODE  | ⟵ translation
205   Iriure EN         en               uk         | ⟵ this is redundant
205   Iriure EN         en               de         | ⟵ non translated (virtual)
...
```

**Problem**:
`translations` table stores only translated & original entities, but I need to add translations also for non translated entities, and this “virtual” records (their fields) should be based on source entity fields.

**Overview**:
There are two tables in this system

`languages` - list of all available languages in the system (example 3)

```
id     langcode
----------------
1        en
2        de
3        uk
```

`translations` - list of source entities and their translations based on source entity (example 4)

```
id     title        langcode    default_langcode   created    changed   ...   ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
205     Iriure EN      en            1            xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx
205     IriUKure       uk            0            xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx
206     UK Nunc UK     uk            1            xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx
207     LucidusDE      de            1            xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx
...
```

To indicate that current row is a source `default_langcode`  (int) column is used, in other case `default_langcode` => 0 means that this is a translation

**Tried solutions**:
One of the solution was using cross join on `languages` table with `default_langcode = 1` only rows but in this case I got fields from source entity on translated ones.
I've used:

```
SELECT 
  translations.id AS id, 
  translations.title,
  translations.langcode AS source, 
  translations.created AS created,
  l.langcode,
  tr.langs as translations_langs, 
  IF(FIND_IN_SET(l.langcode, tr.langs) AND translations.langcode <> l.langcode, 1, 0) as is_translation
FROM 
  translations translations

CROSS JOIN languages l

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    translations.id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(translations.langcode separator ',') as langs, 
    COUNT(translations.langcode) as items
  FROM translations translations 
  GROUP BY translations.id
) AS tr ON translations.id = tr.id

WHERE node_field_data.default_langcode = '1' 

ORDER BY node_field_data.id
```

Another solution that I've tried to use **UNION** but in that case I've got results like in `example 1` with redundant rows.

Query:

```
(SELECT 
  translations.id AS id, 
  translations.title,
  translations.langcode AS source_language, 
  l.langcode as target_language,
  translations.created AS created

FROM 
  translations translations

CROSS JOIN languages l

WHERE 
  translations.default_langcode = '1' 
)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
  translations.id AS id, 
  translations.title,
  translations.langcode AS source_language,
  'DYMMY_LANGCODE' as target_language ,
  translations.created AS created

FROM 
  translations translations

WHERE 
  translations.default_langcode = '0' 
)

ORDER BY id
```

**Summary**:
What I need is just get a difference between all languages and each translation langcodes (where `default_langcode` = 0) and add extra rows with default values (title, changed, and all others) from the source entity (where `default_langcode` = 1)

Personally I would prefer do not use union due to system specific things, but if this the only way then it's ok. 
Ideally I would like to use `translations` table with joins.

**Agreements**: 
row ~ entity ~ record

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I didn't run so may be syntax errors)

```
SELECT t1.Id,
ISNULL(t.title,t1.title+'_'+t1.langcode) title,
t1.source_langcode,
t1.langcode target_langcode,
CASE
WHEN t1.default_langcode = t.langcode THEN '(original)'
WHEN t.langcode IS NULL THEN '(non translated)'
ELSE '(translation)'
END
FROM
(
--GET AllCodes trim suffix
SELECT t.Id,t.title,l.langcode,t.source_language
(SELECT Id,LEFT(title, LEN(title)-3) title, langcode source_language
FROM translations
WHERE default_langcode = 1
) t
JOIN lanquages ON 1=1
) t1
LEFT JOIN translations t ON t1.Id = t.Id AND t1.langcode = t.langcode
```

Comment: Thanks, Ike! But there is no pattern in title field, and also I would like to get any field from source entity. I've cahnged a bit question's description to avoid this misunderstanding.